# Markdown with javax.swing

Tags: java, swing, markdown

I am new to javax.swing, so sorry if my question seems obvious.

I have a markdown file, what would be the correct class/way to represent it using javax.swing?

I have not found a straightforward answer in internet...is it possible to represent a markdown file in an easy way? I don't need to modify it, just show the content.

Thanks everyone

Comment: By ‘show content’, do you mean render it, or just show the raw text?

Comment: "render" it...I mean, if I have the text between the double `*`, I want to see it in bold

Comment: I hope there is some straightforward way to show rich text as markdown or HTML (markdown in my case)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly involved.

There is no swing component that 'natively' renders markdown. There are libraries though, which are entirely unrelated to swing, that turn markdown into something else, usually, HTML.

And there are swing components that render HTML.

1+1 = 2.

Using [TxtMark](https://github.com/rjeschke/txtmark):

```
public void renderMarkdown(String md) {
  String html = txtmark.Processor.process(md);
  JEditorPane editor = ...;
  editor.setContentType("text/html");
  editor.setText(html);
}

renderMarkdown("Hey, *this seems* not __too difficult__");
```

Comment: The JEditorPane can only process HTML 3.2.  This may be sufficient for markdown to HTML.

Comment: Well, technically markdown is just HTML (as in, you can put HTML tags in there and they are to be interpreted as HTML, i.e. not escaped), but the explciit things markdown adds is effectively `<quote>`, `<code>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<ul> <ol> <li>` and `<a>` and those were in HTML 1.0 as far as I remember :)

Comment: I think the most challenging part might be styling the HTML elements.